# Javascript function runs the first time but won't again

Tags: javascript, function

Context behind this, there is another function that listens for a change in an HTML dropdown. When there is a change, the JavaScript calls the costs function and puts in the new variables, which should recalculate the cost.

However, after running this the first time, the code will not run again. I know this because the alert "I AM RUNNING" only appears when the function is called the first time.

Any idea what I am overlooking?

```
function costs(f, p) {
        window.alert("I AM RUNNING");
        costs = [10500, 33950, 33950, 22576, 22576, 22576, 39324, 39324, 39324, 39324, 39324, 0];
        models = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "\u00a0"];
        ind = models.indexOf(f);
        a = ((p/100)*costs[ind]).toFixed(2);
        b = a.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        c = "$"+b;
        return c;
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a complete code example in your question please?

Comment: Check the developer tools log (F12 in most browsers) and see if there are any errors from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining `costs` within the function at line:

```
costs = [10500, 33950, 33950, 22576, 22576, 22576, 39324, 39324, 39324, 39324, 39324, 0];
```

Make it a different variable name.

Comment: Just changing the name would only hide a bug. He should **declare** the inner variables instead of using implicit global ones.

Comment: Thanks, very frustrated I overlooked such a silly mistake